# How to remove element by ID using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add and remove file uploading using javascript.
I am able to add the Element but when I try to remove the same element, it gives the error:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}
```

Below is my HTML code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <p>Upload file(s)</p>
    <div id="files">
        <p><input type="file" name="uploaded_file[]" /></p>
    </div>
    <p><input type="button" value="Add File" onclick="addFile();" /></p>
</form>
```

JS :

```
function addElement(parentId, elementTag, elementId, html) {
    // Adds an element to the document
    var p = document.getElementById(parentId);
    var newElement = document.createElement(elementTag);
    newElement.setAttribute('id', elementId);
    newElement.innerHTML = html;
    p.appendChild(newElement);
}

function removeElement(elementId) {
    // Removes an element from the document
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}


var fileId = 0; // used by the addFile() function to keep track of IDs

window.addFile = function() {
    fileId++; // increment fileId to get a unique ID for the new element
    var html = '<input type="file" name="uploaded_files[]" /> ' +
           '<a href="" onclick="javascript:removeElement("file-' + fileId + '"); return false;">Remove</a>';
    addElement('files', 'p', 'file-' + fileId, html);
}
```

the error seems to be in this line, bu I am not sure

```
var html = '<input type="file" name="uploaded_files[]" /> ' +
           '<a href="" onclick="javascript:removeElement("file-' + fileId + '"); return false;">Remove</a>';
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o093kvo9/)

Comment: The fiddle throws a different error: _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input_

Comment: The error is in the onclick attribute that you are dynamically generating on the remove link. `onclick="javascript:removeElement("` - what comes after that is not part of the attribute value any more, because of the second `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `"file-' + fileId + '"` with `\'file-' + fileId + '\'`.

You're setting a string in html var using '' chars, so you can use freely "" in it: `var html = '<a href="myhref">'`

But when you need to also declare a string inside an already opened double quote, you need to use single quote and escape it so JS knows you're not actually closing the initial single quote at the beginning.
`var html = '<a href="myhref" onclick="functionToCall(\'myStringInsideAnotherString\')">'`

And you can still add dynamic thing using regular (not escaped) single quotes:
`var html = '<a href="myhref" onclick="functionToCall(\'myStringInside' + 
myOtherStringDeclaredSomewhereElse + 'AnotherString\')">'`

Also, in order to make your fiddle to work, you'll need to change the load type to "No wrap" instead of onLoad.